# --delimiter for neo4j import tool

Tags: neo4j

Due to the reason, I need using ";" as the CSV delimiter, according to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/), it can configure the delimiter via `--delimiter ";"` in the arguments, but after a try, it throw the exception like

#### Command

`bin>neo4j-import --into test1.db --id-type string  --nodes E:\workspace\neo4j\neo4j_data\small\company.csv --delimiter ";"`

#### Error

> ... -nodes E:\workspace\neo4j\neo4j_data\small\company.csv --delimiter ;)
>
> ~
>   ..........
>
> -nodes E:\workspace\neo4j\neo4j_data\small\company.csv --delimiter ;)
>                                                                        ~
>       CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],
>
> ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression

Did someone encounter the same problem and how to fix it? thanks.

**BTW:** I'm using win10 64bit

Comment: Please, can you share a small part of `company.csv` file? Thanks.

Comment: Just a very simple file but using ";" as the delimiter.

Comment: You solved your issue?

Comment: Still not, always get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes for the delimiter and specify the array-delimiter too. For example :

```
bin\neo4j-import.bat --into data\databases\aircraft.db --id-type string --nodes L:\neo4j-enterprise-3.2.5\import\company.csv --array-delimiter ',' --delimiter ';'
```

You need the array-delimiter because the default for that is ';' ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom